# How to output Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to a ListBox or anything else?

Tags: c#, wpf, logging

I would like to output all of the logging in a WPF application to a `ListBox` or anything else. The general idea would be to have an `ObservableCollection<T>` that the `ListBox` would be bound to.

However I don't have any idea how I could plug this feature to the following startup sequence.

```
public partial class App
{
    private IHost _host = null!;

    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder =>
                {
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                {
                    builder
                        .SetBasePath(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json", false)
                        .AddCommandLine(e.Args);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((context, collection) =>
                {
                    collection
                        .Configure<AppSettings>(context.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)))
                        .AddSingleton<MainWindow>()
                        .AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, builder) =>
                {
                    builder.AddDebug();
                })
            ;

        _host = hostBuilder.Build();

        await _host.StartAsync();

        var window = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();

        window.Show();
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnExit(e);

        using (_host)
        {
            _host.StopAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0d));
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose it should be pluggable as an extension method, pretty much like `builder.AddDebug` but that's about it.

**Question:**

How can I extend Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to output logging to a `ListBox` for instance?

Comment: You need to implement a [custom logging provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider). In this case, it would be somewhat tricky because you'd need to have a cache of logs that are sent before the UI exists, and then have some way of hooking the logging provider up to the UI when it is ready.

Comment: @StephenCleary The second part is required anyway in an MVP app. You wouldn't store the data (the logs) directly in the window anyway.

Comment: @StephenCleary I've just tried that and indeed it's tricky, multiple instances of ILogger are created by ILoggerProvider.CreateLogger... I've updated my question but not sure what to do next.

Comment: @aybe There's only one instance of your `ILoggerProvider`. You can create the container in there and provide it to the loggers when `CreateLogger` is called, so that all loggers operate on the same instance (with appropriate locking, of course). That's actually the same as when logging to a file, that requires synchronization as well.

Comment: @PMF This is amazing, so simple yet so efficient, I did what you said, then injected the logger provider to the view, I try cast the provider to an interface which exposes that observable collection, works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

We have a beginning of an answer thanks to **@StephenCleary** and **@PMF** comments:

The custom `ILogger`:

```
public sealed class MyCustomLogger : ILogger
{
    public MyCustomLogger(string category, ObservableCollection<string> collection)
    {
        Category   = category;
        Collection = collection;
    }

    private string Category { get; }

    private ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get; }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        var message = formatter(state, exception);

        message = $"{Category}: {message}";

        Collection.Add(message);
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return new NullScope();
    }

    private class NullScope : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The custom `ILoggerProvider`:

```
public sealed class MyCustomLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider, IObservableLoggerProvider
{
    public MyCustomLoggerProvider()
    {
        Entries = Collection;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get; } = new();

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new MyCustomLogger(categoryName, Collection);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string>? Entries { get; }
}
```

The extension method to plug the logger in `ConfigureLogging`:

```
public static class MyCustomLoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddCustomLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddConfiguration();

        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, MyCustomLoggerProvider>()
        );

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Now I've added this interface to the provider:

```
public interface IObservableLoggerProvider
{
    ObservableCollection<string>? Entries { get; }
}
```

In the view model I look for that provider with that interface:

```
public sealed class MainViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    public MainViewModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Log from MainViewModel 1");

        var service = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerProvider>();
        if (service is IObservableLoggerProvider provider)
        {
            Entries = provider.Entries;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string>? Entries { get; }
}
```

Whenever I click that button to log something, the `ListBox` actualizes itself:

[image]

Thanks guys, both of your suggestions worked perfectly!

Comment: Suggestion: I typically implement `IsEnabled` as `public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => logLevel >= _minLogLevel;` with `_minLogLevel` being provided from the factory as well. But I'm not exactly sure where the infrastructure does that test (I never debugged that part).

Comment: Yes, it's not yet finished, tbh I'm more concerned about locking as you said, I tried BindingOperations but it didn't work so likely I'm gonna have to get my hands dirty to address that.